# Anyone remember Agilix ink controls for .net? (Tablet pc)

Tags: c#, .net, controls, tablet-pc, microsoft.ink

I am finally updating an old app that targeted some ink functions. At the time we used the Agilix controls to get a lot of ink functions. Basically it was infinotes in a single control.

Does anyone know a replacement for Agilix since it seems the company no longer has support or controls like this.

Maybe this will jog your memory
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms812500.aspx

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember it quite well. Used it in my own application. Unfortunately there was never anything then nor is there now that can be used as a drop-in replacement for that kind of functionality.

If you were using WPF you could start off with an [InkCanvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.inkcanvas.aspx) control which has built-in support for the standard set of modes (writing, selecting, erasing) and supports child controls (such as TextBox controls.) But it isn't as polished. Not that Infinotes didn't have its own problems too, but it had pretty good support for mixing text and ink in the same page.

You can also make use of the [InkAnalyzer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms704040.aspx) classes to parse ink into paragraphs, lines, words, and drawings the way Infinotes used to do. But how you deal with that data once its parsed is up to you.